# Once saved in eclipse, copy project to a different directory

Tags: eclipse

Using Eclipse, is there a way to automatically copy a file/project's directory to a different path once it's saved?

Effectively, when i save a file, it copies it from the workspace to the deploy directory

```
Workspace: "/code/my_app"
deploy to: "/application/plugins/my_app"
```

**EDIT:**

This is Mainly for Python and PHP projects

Comment: post edit: ant's copy still works. obviously the javac task is useless to you, but the copy and exec tasks are still good tools, no matter what language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org) pretty easily. There's even an Ant View in eclipse to run the script from. See the [copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html).

Here's a sample ant build.xml file:

```
<project name="whatever" default="copy">
    <target name="copy">
        <copy todir="someDir">
          <fileset dir="someOtherDir/" casesensitive="yes">
            <include name="**/*.java"/>
            <exclude name="**/*Test*"/>
          </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
</project>
```

You can also add more targets for deploying your application.

Comment: I'm trying it right now, I guess I'm missing something ... So in external tools, i created an ANT Build, But i'm not sure where to put the copy code   <copy todir="../new/dir">
    <fileset dir="src_dir"/>
  </copy>

Comment: i added sample build.xml content

Answer (score 1):

Try [“Ant Builder”](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-93_project_builder.htm) :).

i have not tried this but this looks nearly what you want.